# How to extract Facebook messenger password

Tags: applications, facebook-messenger

I would like to ask you how can i see the stored password of FB messenger on my phone.

What i already tried:

- Password reset did not work since the mail that was used is blocked and the phone number is in the bottom of the sea so no access there too.
- It is not logged on with another website or application to get the password from there
- Facebook support do not reply to the requests to reset the password

Please let me know what else i can try to find my saved password.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually such apps like FB messenger don't save the password at all. They use username/password for authentication the first time and then get back an oAuth token that is used afterwards for authentication. The oAuth token is random and therefore can't be used to get back the password.

Comment: Dear Robert, so i understand that in that case there is no way to retrieve the password from the app or any other option. So im guessing the only option is to work with FB directly to reset the password.

Comment: Hi Ritorio, I have not analyzed FM messenger how it authenticates, I just said what is usually used. Anyway FB messenger disallows local backup via ADB therefore even if it would save the password you would need root permissions to get access to the private app data of FB messenger.